# Homeomorphisms that admit a decomposition

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, measure-theory, special-functions, fractional-iteration

Let $I^n:=[0,1]^n$ and $T$ be a homeomorphism on $I^n$.
If $T$ admits a decomposition of $I^n=A\cup B\cup C$ with $A,B,C$ Lebesgue measurable and mutually disjoint such that $$T(A)=B,  T(B)=A \ \text{and}\   m(C)=0,$$ 
where $m(C)$ is the Lebesgue measure of $C$, then
 What is the general solution of $T$?
I know some examples of $T$, such as  $T$ with $T^{\circ 2k}=Id$ admits such a decomposition.
Another example, $T(x)=(t_1(x_1),t_2(x),...,t_n(x))$ with $t_1$ strictly monotone also admits a decomposition.

Comment: What do you mean by "solution"?

Comment: I mean other explicit way to describe $T$ or a general formula of $T$ perhaps.

Comment: I think this question is interesting, but I don't quite understand the choice of tags. Maybe measure-theory and ds.dynamical-systems and more appropriate.

Comment: Do you know the answer for $[0,1]$? Modulo conjugating by homeomoprhism of $[0,1]$, there seems to be only one map.

Comment: @plusepsilon.de On $[0,1]$, T can be only monotone  so it  admits such a decomposition if $T$ have countable fixed points. I am not sure if this is a necessary condition.

Comment: There are only two strictly monotone functions on $[0,1]$ up to conjugation by homeomorphisms. One doesn meet your criteria.

Comment: @plusepsilon.de  Which two?

Comment: @plusepsilon.de: Functions with different numbers of fixed points can't be conjugates, and the number of fixed points could be any integer $\ge 1$.

Comment: Okay, my mistake;) I see now that it seems to more complicated...

Comment: Related Questions: Is the set of such homeomorphisms a closed subset of all homeomorphisms? Does a homeomorphism preserve null-sets (I guess no, but I don't see a counterexample)?. I am thinking of constructing an example using Bing-involutions, but I am not sure about the fixed point sets.

Comment: Homeomorphisms don't preserve null sets.  For example, there is a homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ to itself that maps the usual Cantor set to a "fat" 
Cantor set of positive Lebesgue measure.  Homeomorphisms that are bi-Lipschitz preserve null sets.

Answer (score 1):

Obvious necessary condition: the set of fixed points and periodic points of odd order must have measure $0$.

EDIT: And there's another class of examples that do not admit such a decomposition.
Suppose there is a probability measure $\mu$ invariant under $T$ which is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. Then if $T$ admits a decomposition, it can't be strongly mixing with respect to $\mu$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.